# How to add a transformation in Spotfire to remove the numbers at the end of a string if exists

Tags: string, spotfire

How can I remove the numbers at the end of a string if exists, here is a example of the column:

ceberster
ceberster5500
wasegse5500
wasegse
tere5500
tere

I tried with STRIP but I don't seem to have STRIP function in my spotfire...

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data source, some functions might/might not be available to you. If *RXReplace* is in your list, then you could try this custom expression to calculate a column:

```
RXReplace([your column],'\\d+$','','g')
```

where you are replacing numbers at the end with an empty string. If there are characters after the numbers, it will not replace anything (so you need to be sure the numbers are always trailing in your case). If you want to replace all numbers, regardless of where they appear in the string, remove the $.

You could apply it as a Calculate and replace column transformation in the data canvas, if you don't want to generate a new column.